# Custom value for safe-area-inset CSS SCSS

Tags: css, sass

How do I set a custom value for environmental-variable in case if display has cutouts?

Assuming that browser **supports** ENV

If I set:

```
padding-left: env(safe-area-inset-left)
```

In this case:

if display has cutouts (left side) - the browser will set it's **own specific value**;

if it has not (rectangle) - the value will be `0px`

QUESTION: How do I set a custom value (lets say 30px) instead of browser's one?

To be clear, I want - 30px padding from left if display has cutouts, and 20px is display is a rectangle.

How it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the new CSS `clamp()` to ensure you keep a value between 20 and 30 pixels.

```css
.block {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-left: clamp(20px, 20px + env(safe-area-inset-left), 30px);
}
```

Using this method, the middle value `20px + env(safe-area-inset-left)` will resolve to `20px + 0px` on rectangular displays, and `20px + 50px` (`50px` being an example). The clamping from 20 to 30 pixels will ensure the value stays within that range. Adding a fallback will ensure browsers that don't ship `env()` or `clamp()` will still have a `20px` padding value.

EDIT: I find the `clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)` situation clearer to understand but since the VAL is the `MIN + something`, you could also simplify it to `min(20px + env(safe-area-inset-left), 30px)`.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for